# How to import Xamarin project correctly?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, rider

I got a Xamarin Android/iOS project for improving (I'm native Android and iOS developer). It is presented in folders:

MainProject/

- MainProject
- MainProject-Android
- MainProject-iOS

When I open one of this folders in Visual Studio or Rider (on macOS), I always have linking and compilation error.

How I can import this project correctly (mostly in Rider)? Or maybe I got crashed project?

Comment: you open the solution (.sln) file

Comment: @Jason in what folder?

Comment: Typically in the root folder.  But I don't know how yours is setup.

Comment: in the root usually. Or you can create and empty solution and add all these projects there. In Rider you can go to the Solution Explorer and click ''Add Existing Project..." on the solution node

Answer (score 2):

To make it clear, I add a screenshot here, you should double click `projectName.sln` to open the project in Visual-Studio:

[image]

BTW, you can try to delete the `bin and obj` folder in each project and then run again. This sometimes will fix the linking and compilation error.